# How do you compute the following triple integral? Please help....

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\int\limits_{-2}^{2}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\, dz\,dy\,dx$$

How do I solve this? Whenever you do triple integral, aren't you supposed to use 
$$\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{} 1 dzdydx$$

But a function is given....

Please don't use some crazy formulas or theorems to solve this. I just want the simplest and the most efficient way to solve this (e.g. using polar, switching integrations, etc.)

Thank you

Comment: Use spherical coordinates.

Comment: could you show how?

Answer (score 2):

The integral looks like a candidate for spherical coordinates, but the tricky part is figuring out the integration limits.  The way to do this is to sketch a picture of the integration region you have been given.  Unfortunately, you write your integral in a way that obfuscates the region a bit (who is going from $[-2,2]$?).

No matter.  If you draw a picture, you will see that the region is a section of a sphere of radius $2$ in which $x>0$, $z>0$, and $y \in [-2,2]$.  This implies that, for the angles, $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$ and $\phi \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.  The integral then becomes, remembering that a volume element in sphericals is $dx dy dz = r^2 \sin{\theta} \, dr \, d\theta\, d\phi$:

$$\int_0^2 dr \, r^3 \: \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \sin{\theta} \: \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\phi$$

**EDIT**

Perhaps the OP meant that the limit in the 2nd integral should be $\sqrt{4-x^2}$. Then the domain of integration is $y>0$ and $x \in [-2,2]$.  Then $\phi \in [0,\pi]$ and the integral becomes

$$\int_0^2 dr \, r^3 \: \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \sin{\theta} \: \int_{0}^{\pi} d\phi$$

which does not change the result.  But it does illustrate why it is important to be clear when writing out triple integrals.  Note that keeping the variables with the integrals makes the value unambiguous.

Comment: I think that acording to the order of $\,dz\,dy\,dx\,$ , it is $\,-2\le x\le2\,$ and not $\,y\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio: yeah, but look at his integration limits.  The second one has a limit that is a function of $y$.

Comment: Indeed so, @Ron, yet I'd go for a typo of the OP: the upper limit in the second integral should be $\,\sqrt{4-x^2}\,$ ...

Comment: Yeah, this is why I write my integrals the way I do.  I took the other tack, that the integration limits determine which variable goes with which integral. But I can do it the other way to illustrate why the whole way of writing multiple integrals out like this is foolish.

Comment: I'd do it the way to did in your edit, @Ron, yet I'd use the angles interchanged. Behold here https://www.google.co.il/search?q=spherical+coordinates&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=2wxuUZTZEYLX0QWcioC4Bg&sqi=2&ved=0CDcQsAQ&biw=1245&bih=619 to see what a mess this is...I already forgot! Sometimes $\,\theta\,$ is the angle on the $\,xy\,$ plane, others the one on the $\,xz\,$ plane. Hard to know which one's more widespread used.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I am a physicist and this is how I learned it in all of my math and physics classes, as well as in my work in industry.  I have seen it the other way, and yes, what a mess.  Hard to say who favors what way over the other.  But at least it is clear what I mean - it is the $xz$ angle that has the sine.

Comment: You're a physicist?! My deepest condolences...:) Now seriously: my best friends while in undergraduate school were physicists and we took together the basic program in mathematics. They were fine (I guess..), but when we got into graduate school your should have heard their whinning about the mathematics: they could hardly handle it. That's when I became very appreciated there...

Comment: @DonAntonio: some of my best friends are...yeah, yeah. :)  Seriously, I was in it for the math - the insane diffraction integrals that turned most people away.  I probably should have been a mathematician, but too late for that now.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do a triple integral of a function.  Start with the innermost one, which is over $z$.  You consider $x$ and $y$ to be constants, so you are computing $$\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dz$$  This is a fairly standard form and you can keep going.

The easier way is to realize that you are integrating $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=r$over a quarter of a sphere-the sphere has radius $2$, centered on the origin, but is restricted to $y\ge 0, z \ge 0$  So the solid angle is $\pi$ and you have $$\pi\int_0^2r^3dr$$ where the other two factors of $r$ came from the jacobian.

Comment: Why are you integrating $r$ over $[-2,2]$?  Isn't $r>0$?

Comment: @RonGordon:  right.